# Float Left 100% height div - gap between divs

Tags: html, css, css-float

**Mark Up**

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="test.aspx.cs" Inherits="Zuhaib.test" %>
<!-- Put IE into quirks mode -->
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <link href="css/general.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="css/outbound.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server" class="wrapper">
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
    </asp:ScriptManager>
    <div id="left">
    </div>
    <div id="right">
    </div>  
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
html, body
{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    border:0;
    overflow:hidden;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
* html body 
{
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
}    
*{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
.wrapper 
{
    position:fixed;
    top:0px;
    bottom:0px;
    left:0px;
    right:0px;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
}
* html .wrapper 
{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
#left{
    float:left;
    height:100%;
    width:100px;
    overflow:hidden;
    background-color:Blue;
}
* html #left{
    height:100%;
    width:100px;
}
#right{
    margin-left:100px;
    height:100%;
    background-color:Red;
}
* html #right{
    height:100%;
}
```

**Result in IE && FF**
[Resutls in IE & FF http://img139.imageshack.us/img139/9871/ie3pxgapnl4.jpg](http://img139.imageshack.us/img139/9871/ie3pxgapnl4.jpg)
The result is same with both IE 6 & 7. How can I remove the gap between the divs?

**Udate**
I have two divs each with 100% height. the left div is a fixed width floating div. Even after giving correct margin-left to the right div, there remains a gap (3px) between the two divs. Where as in firefox it renders correctly.

The reason I have used quirk mode is to able to get 100% height for the divs

Can this gap be eliminated? Or is there a better way to do two column 100% height layout with pure css?

Comment: Try adding more explanation about what you tried and what happened.  It doesn't seem like you put too much effort into asking your question.

Comment: Why is it that newbie question always get downvoted first-hand.... most are legitimate questions!

Comment: This is not a newbie question. The question is pretty self-explanatory. Why is there a gap between the floating div? don’t you understand html?? Mr. Randy Stegbauer you shouldn’t be viewing this if you could not understand the problem from the title and content. Or you dont care to read the problem.

Comment: @Randy, how much more explanation do you want? ZuhaibZ has provided full source code, a picture of the result and a succinct description of the problem and his desired solution. Downvoting this is pathetic.

Comment: @Randy: To be fair its a completely legitimate question. He's asked his question in grammatically correct english which is more than I can say for some of the dross on SO and he's provided more background info and samples that most people bother.

Comment: I would downvote Randsy's comment if it could be possible. This is very nice made question with good info and images.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As already said, your code is full of hacks. Please remove especially the unnecessary definitions. If a browser does not support *cascading* style sheets, it will not support CSS anyway.

That being said, why not use position: absolute; for #right?

As in

```
#right{
  position: absolute;
  left: 100px;
  padding-left: -100px;
  width: 100%;
  ...
}
```

Comment: absolute positioning will definitely solve the problem. Looks like the only solution to me.. Thank you

Answer (score 3):

Remove the comment on top of the page
The "Put IE into quirks mode" thing

You are using a lot of 'hacks'. By that I mean the CSS selectors that begin with * html

I'm not saying that is the cause of the problem, but it is not good practice and is error prone.

1) try using conditional comments for the browser that has the gap problem instead of using those hacks
2) try editing your question by providing information about the version of IE you're testing against (my guess is IE 6 or even lower).

Comment: I have tested using IE 6 & 7, results are same. I have used the hack's to get 100% height for the div.

Comment: * html is not error-prone.  It is perfectly invalid CSS that happens to work in IE 5-6 and is a reliable way to target IE6.  Now that everyone knows it doesn't target IE7 there's no danger to using this.

Answer (score 2):

To be honest, if you're filling up the whole body with these divs, then you're better off giving one of them a transparent background and setting the background color of the body to the desired color, masking the problem.

Especially if, in trying to solve the IE issue, you're introducing a plague of CSS hacks into what should be nice and clean code considering the simple layout you're shooting for.

Comment: ...plus the page would resize better.

Answer (score 1):

The actual problem is the whitespace between the closing div tag and the next opening div tag.  If you put them together on the same line with no space between them, or fill in the white space with a comment, the whitespace will be gone.

```
<div id="left">
</div><div id="right">
</div>
```

or

```
  <div id="left">
    </div><!-- IE doesn't ignore whitespace between divs
  --><div id="right">
     </div>
```